# disabling external stylesheets

Tags: css

I'm working on an expedia affiliate site and am having trouble with overriding styles provided by expedia with my own styles. Expedia allows me to upload my own header file and link to external stylesheets, however I haven't managed to override the default styles completely.

I've even gone to the extent of cloning the default stylesheets provided by expedia and replacing the styles one by one. [Here's](http://travel.ian.com/hotel/searchresults?currencyCode=USD&userCity=maldives%2C++%2CMV&additionalDataString=vrBookingSource|hotNetList&locale=en_US_US&searchParam=21DE2207-5A29-406B-9D2D-32262BD870DE&searchType=DESTINATION&cid=348206) the url.

```
.js div#map.ma p-expanded {
    background-image: url("/zen/_media/_global/loading-large.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

I've tried to change the background of this map to white but failed at all attempts.

Comment: You'd do better to just show us the relevant code.

Comment: well, what you can do is overwrite the class names and other declaration on the css you don't want. You can't replace the file. Although you can remove the `<style>` element with javscript.

Answer (score 0):

The !important declaration may help you override some styles set by the expedia stylesheet.

```
margin{ 0 !important; }
```

Useful reading: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

EDIT: Just tried this, it works for me.

```
.map-expanded{
   background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: For further clarification, the following declarations control the styling of the expanded map. I have tried !important and appending this exact declaration with background-color:white  in my custom stylesheet to change the bg color but doesn't seem to work.

.js div#map.map-expanded {
    background-image: url("/zen/_media/_global/loading-large.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

Comment: From what I can see in the source you haven't tried that. Download firebug, it really will help you when playing around with css :)

Comment: Unfortunately even the entire CSS path (html.js body#cid-348206.lang-en div#page div#page-header div#page-content div#content div#map.map-expanded) doesn't work. Perhaps its a problem with the HTML structure itself?

Answer (score 0):

Look up "css precedence", there are simple rules that determine which style will be applied. For instance [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

You could for instance create more specified classes than the expedia styles.

The style applied by `.js div#map.map-expanded` would be overridden by your definition if you specify it more, e.g. `div.js div#map.map-expanded` (if the js class is set on a div element).